# Most dangerous stunts in film

Tags: cinema-history, stunts

When researching a different question, I came across an [article on horse stunts](https://www.ponybox.com/news_details.php?id=3578&title=Most-Dangerous-Horse-Movie-Stunts), which claimed that a stunt from the John Wayne movie [*Stagecoach*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagecoach_(1939_film)) was one of the most difficult and dangerous stunts on film.

> Wayne is replaced by stunt rider Yakima Cannute in a dramatic scene where the hero jumps aboard a galloping horse that’s part of a team pulling a stagecoach. He leaps from horse to horse, trying to get control of the reins before getting shot. He then falls in between the horses, slides down the pole between them, under the coach, and is then left in the dust as other riders gallop by. It’s said to be one of the most difficult and dangerous stunts on film. It was filmed once, and in one shot.

Is this in fact the most difficult/dangerous stunt, or is there a general list/consensus of what are considered to be the most dangerous stunts to attempt when filming?

Comment: You've misquoted your own quoted insert. There is a lot of difference between *'**one** of the most difficult and dangerous'* and *'**the** most difficult/dangerous'*.

Comment: Does any stunt that killed someone automatically count as more dangerous?

Comment: Ben Hur would feature then but any list would be based on some opinions which would make this off-topic. I think it's probably trivia too.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica - No. Brandon Lee was killed by a malfunctioning prop in a shooting scene, that doesn't make that type of stunt (being fired at by blanks) inherently more dangerous.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I would argue that knowing the relative danger of stunts enhances the appreciation of films that feature said stunts.

Comment: But the list is opinion nevertheless. My definition of dangerous is different to others. There is no objective scale here.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Hrm. Possibly true. Complexity or difficulty perhaps?

Comment: I mean the stunts in Hooper for instance seem more dangerous than Stagecoach but that's just me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102177/discussion-between-johnp-and-paulie-d).

Comment: @Paulie_D, while I would agree that the list would be opinionated, there might be some lists out there that are "expert opinionated" (people in the field). Even in legal cases, juries rely on "expert witness" opinions all the time to lay out facts.

Answer (score 2):

*The French Connection* car chase is arguably more dangerous in that the car chase was filmed without permits on mostly uncleared roads and most of the near-misses and one full-hit to a car were on open streets with unaware bystanders.

They did have some control and informal permission on several blocks because they had police on the set etc., but they did not stay in this area for the whole thing.